# Is the Devil Sams father?

Tags: character, reaper

In the TV series Reaper the main character Sam has to capture escaped souls from Hell and the request of Satan himself. As the show continues it turns out Sams parent are demons and sold his soul to the Devil and that is why Sam has to carry out these task. I'm sure there was a storyline that the Devil was actually Sams father and when confronted about it the Devil replies something like 'I'm the Devil, you wouldn't believe me if I said no'. Does anyone know if Satan was Sams father or not? I could only stream the show in the U.K. but the show got cut before it ended  sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaper_(TV_series)#Samuel_%22Sam%22_Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was never 'confirmed' as it was cancelled before any validation or confirmation, I was a huge fan of this show and I was devastated when it was cut short, a couple of minor issues with your statement, his parents sold his soul to the devil for wealth I believe, like the good old 'first born pacts' I do think that's where the show was going though as it was hinted, or we where led to believe that, I remember near the end Sam tried to win his soul back playing coin flip, but fails obviously. If they revived this show I'd be so happy!

Comment: the show was fantastic, especially Soc.